# Figure code and uniform code merger

Tags: c#, performance

Below I have a simple method that will merge a figure code with a uniform code, let me talk more about that and how it works so you guys have a neat understanding.

Each character on my gaming emulator has a unique figure code, unless their dressed the exact same of course but unlikely, here is an example of a few figure codes.

```
lg-285-76.hr-155-31.sh-300-92.ca-1819-63.hd-209-2.ch-3030-76
he-3149-1331.sh-3035-110.hr-170-61.fa-3276-72.ch-255-110.hd-209-2.lg-280-1331
ch-210-110.hd-209-7.hr-828-1407.he-3082-63.lg-280-1408.cp-3309-77.sh-290-92
```

Above is 3 examples of a figure string, I wont go as far as explaining each part as its not relevant in this question (as of now).

So, each character has a figure code and then there is a few uniform codes. Now the uniform codes usually only contain the `ch` and `lg` parts for chest and leg, which is usually all a uniform needs, except I have coded this method to replace any parts of the uniform into the figure code with the uniform part. Here is a few examples of the uniform figure codes..

```
(Legs, Shoes and Chest)
lg-285-76.sh-300-92.ca-1819-63.ch-3030-76
(Legs and Chest)
lg-280-110.ch-1004-110
```

So what am I asking?
I am asking for some ways to improve the performance of this method.

Edit: I've added functionality to choose which parts you want to replace, with a list string as the second parameter, which is default empty (replaces all parts).

Here is the method:

```
public static string ReturnUniform(string uniform, string figure, List<string> partsToReplace = new List<string>())
{
    List<string> uniformParts = uniform.Split('.').ToList();
    List<string> figureParts = uniform.Split('.').ToList();

    foreach (string uniformPart in uniformParts)
    {
        string[] parts = uniformPart.Split('-');
        string part = parts[0];

        if (partsToReplace.Any() && !partsToReplace.Contains(part))
        {
            continue;
        }

        if (figure.Contains(part + "-"))
        {
            var indexOfItem = figureParts.ToList().FindIndex(value => value.StartsWith(part));
            figureParts[indexOfItem] = uniformPart;
        }
        else
        {
            figureParts.Add(uniformPart);
        }
    }

    return string.Join(".", figureParts);
}
```

Comment: There is a bug in the method signature. `List<string> partsToReplace = new List<string>()` a default value must be a compile-time constant. Could you fix this please and perhaps add an example how to use it?

Comment: Here lies some string based programming. Be careful!

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly what you need is to make this method faster.
Firstly, you need to answer one simple question **is that really what you NEED**, this method does not look that time consuming at all (unless you have hundreads of elements in that string). Have you benchmarked it and saw that it consumes a lot of time?

EDIT: it came to me that you might be asking about performance of your idea, if so - for me it looks good enough.

If you really need to make this method faster here is what I can see:

**1.** Do not use `foreach` loop. If you decided to make `uniform.Split('.')` a list take advantage of it. Change your loop to `for`

**2.** Do not use LINQ at all, it is known for being time consuming (since it <s>enumerates everything</s>call enumerator in every function).

```
partsToReplace.Any() && !partsToReplace.Contains(part)
```

can be changed to `for` loop when you do `Any` by `List.Count` method and `Contains` by simply checking every element. Exactly the same thing is applicable to `if (figure.Contains(part + "-"))` and `var indexOfItem = figureParts.ToList().FindIndex(value => value.StartsWith(part));`

in the latter I think you do not need to make `ToList()` but I have no compiler at hand to check it.

**Note**
Those changes are micro optimalisations, if your application is slow it is probably because of some other part. Plase do propper benchmark to check this.

**Also** : I think there should be `List<string> figureParts = figure.Split('.').ToList();`

Comment: `figure.Split('.')` returns an array so making a list of it is counterproductive and requires to reiterate the arrray.

Comment: `Do not use LINQ at all, it is known for being time consuming (since it enumerates everything)`. This is simply not true, specially when you use `Any` or `All`

Comment: @BrunoCosta okay tell me then why is that no true? Isn't there enumerator being called? From what I recall both `Any` and `All`call `foreach` loop which is esentially enumerating. I think I might misspeled my intention `enumerates everything` was not ment to be `enumerates whole collection` but rather `uses enumerator every time` I will fix this now.

Comment: @MaLiN2223 Yup that's better.

Answer (score 1):

As far as my knowledge goes `C#` is an object oriented language and not a string oriented language. What I mean by this is that most people at some point in time commit the mistake of doing everything with strings this is just an example that scratches the surface.

I would (not) like to see how the rest of your code looks like. By the looks of it should do string manipulations at all the time.

So the question should instead be focused on how to approach the equipment of a player of the game. Consider for instance that the player can have legs, shoes and a chest.

We start by specifying this by the very beginning which is a piece of equipment.

```
public interface IEquipment{
    string Id{get; set;}
}
```

This Id would let to put those magic numbers that currently appear on a string. This interface doesn't do anything yet. We do not know any type of functionality of the equipment. We also need to know the type of equipment...

```
public interface IEquipment{
    string Id{get;}
    IEquipmentSlot Slot{get;}
    IEnumerable<IBonus> Modifiers{get;}
    int Durability{get; set;}
}
```

This is just a hypothetical example of a very simple and common game could model their equipment into.  The OP however never specified properties such as modifiers or durability so I won't go further with the idea.

The `IEquipmentSlot`, or something that tells which slot that piece of equipment belongs to, however, seems to be critical. Since you have some options on that regard.

Consider than the following implementation.

```
public class Equipment : IEquipment{
    public Equipment(string id, IEquipmentSlot slot){
        Id = id;
        Slot = slot;
    }

    public string Id{get; private set;}
    public IEquipmentSlot Slot{get; private set;}
}
```

Now imagine the following player class

```
public class Player{
    private IEquipment _legs;
    public IEquipment Legs{
       get{return _legs;} 
       set{
           if(value != EquipmentSlot.Legs){
               throw new InvalidOperationException(
                    "Cannot replace equipment with another type of equipment");
           }
           _legs = value;
       }
   }
}
```

And for the sake of completeness the `Equipment Slot` class:

```
public class EquipmentSlot : IEquipmentSlot{
    public static readonly EquipmentSlot Legs = new EquipmentSlot();
    public static readonly EquipmentSlot Chest = new EquipmentSlot();
    public static readonly EquipmentSlot Shoes = new EquipmentSlot();
}
```

And now we would like to replace a player piece of equipment...

```
public class Example{
    public void ReplaceEquipment(){
        var player = new Player();
        player.Legs = new Equipment("123-45", EquipmentSlot.Legs);
    }
}
```

This is obviously a minimalistic and just an example approach. Your code instead of doing anything even remotely similar is just dealing with strings which, provided there is enough memory, can represent everything in the universe. And worse than that are really hard to code with.

Comment: Note to myself. `C#` is not an object oriented language but it is a multi paradigm language, that's why I like it!